# How can I add dynamic text from a different table where primary key is a foreign key to adynamic table being shown?

Tags: php, mysql

I have here a dynamic table named tb_user with column region_id and institute_id and both ids are primary key of another table tb_region (with column region_name and region_id) and tb_institute (column institute_id and institute_name). I wanted to see region_name and institute_name instead of the ids.

I've used this php script

```
<?php echo $row_institute['institution_name']; ?>
```

and query to collect data for tb_institute

```
mysql_select_db($database_connection_ched, $connection_ched);
$query_institution = "SELECT institute_id, institute_name FROM   tb_institute";
$institution = mysql_query($query_institution, $connection_ched) or die(mysql_error());
$row_institution = mysql_fetch_assoc($institution);
$totalRows_institution = mysql_num_rows($institution);
```

but it seems not to display the correct name of id.

query i used to collect data:

```
mysql_select_db($database_connection_ched, $connection_ched);
$query_notification = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE status = 'inactive' ORDER BY     date_register ASC", GetSQLValueString($colname_notification, "text"));
$query_limit_notification = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_notification,     $startRow_notification, $maxRows_notification);
$notification = mysql_query($query_limit_notification, $connection_ched) or die(mysql_error());
$row_notification = mysql_fetch_assoc($notification);


if (isset($_GET['totalRows_notification'])) {
  $totalRows_notification = $_GET['totalRows_notification'];
} else {
  $all_notification = mysql_query($query_notification);
  $totalRows_notification = mysql_num_rows($all_notification);
}
$totalPages_notification = ceil($totalRows_notification/$maxRows_notification)-1;
```

Comment: Please post the query you're using to get the data.

Comment: Where's the query that sets `$row_institute`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$row_institution['institute_name']
```

instead of

```
$row_institute['institution_name']
```